How to reasonable link disable or hot reset a PCIe devie?
I'm testing a raid card which uses a PCIe link with my server.
There are two ways to link down in PCIe protocol: link disable and hot reset. I didn't find any reasonable way to both do the reset and make a notification to the kernel. So I choose to use the setpci tool to do this, such as triggering a hot reset:
bc=$(setpci -s $port BRIDGE_CONTROL)
echo "Bridge control:" $bc
setpci -s $port BRIDGE_CONTROL=$(printf "%04x" $(("0x$bc" | 0x40)))
sleep 0.01
setpci -s $port BRIDGE_CONTROL=$bc

But the Linux kernel will not sense this link down, thus, the card driver does not sense the device is also unavailable.
When I try to re-probe my card via the driver, the software has to wait for I/O queue timeout and then trigger host reset. The queue timeout is 60 seconds, so I must wait at least 60 seconds to complete the reprobe process.
I want to know if there is any reasonable way in Linux to both do the reset and make a notification to the kernel, such as flr using /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/reset so that the card driver could get the link down status and reprobe my card faster?

Is this driver is only in use by this card?  If so then you could try to rmmod it then modprobe to reinsert it.   This won't work if the OS thinks the driver is in use (eg by another module or a user space program).  Perhaps providing what driver is in use and lsmod | grep driver output...
